# "include" does not include dependency in build jar

Tags: gradle

when i do `gradlew` build the resulting jar does not include the dependencies and won't compile if I don't do "implementation" too.

I tried using only "implementation" but that didn't include the dependency too.

if it'll help here is the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"
    
    include("org.openjdk.nashorn:nashorn-core:15.4")
    implementation "org.openjdk.nashorn:nashorn-core:15.4"
}
```